# Trapping calendar change broadcast receiver

Tags: android, calendar

I would like to receive a broadcast if a calendar is changed. The following code works if the calendar is changed locally in the calendar app. What I would like is if the calendar is changed **remotely**, via an online sync, it also fired the change broadcaster.

My code is as follows

```
    filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED);
    filter.addDataScheme("content");
    filter.addDataAuthority("com.android.calendar", null);
    registerReceiver(new CalendarChangesReceiver(), filter);
```

and class receiver class is

```
public class CalendarChangesReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

CalendarChanged calChanged;

public interface CalendarChanged {
    void onCalendarChanged();
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    calChanged = (CalendarChanged) context;
    ((CalendarChanged) context).onCalendarChanged();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The following code works if the calendar is changed locally in the calendar app

That will depend entirely on the calendar app. For example, there is no requirement for a calendar app to use the `CalendarContract` content provider. And, even for calendar apps that *do* use `CalendarContract`, they do not need to have the code that triggers an `ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED` broadcast.

> What I would like is if the calendar is changed remotely, via an online sync, it also fired the change broadcaster

Once again, that will depend entirely on the calendar app.

Comment: So any suggestions on how to achieve what I want, other than every few seconds refreshing the data?

Comment: @PeterB: Well, "every few seconds refreshing the data" will not necessarily work either. Calendar apps do not have to have calendar data available for other apps to access, whether via `CalendarContract` or by any other means. Those that do make calendar data available do not have to use `CalendarContract` -- they might offer their own APIs instead. So, rather than thinking generally about "a calendar", you might consider focusing on specific calendar apps and determining what your options are for integrating with them that gives you what you want.

Comment: The standard Android installed Calendar can manage the accounts and it will manage sync requests. I will just keep my calendar inline with that one, so whenever it receives changes, I need them to auto populate my app.

Comment: @PeterB: "The standard Android installed Calendar" -- there is no single "Android installed Calendar". What apps come pre-installed is up to the device manufacturer.